# get the latest, second to the latest, and 3rd to the latest record from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

is there any way to get the latest, second to the latest, and 3rd to the latest record from database in different query? because i want to use each query for my slider image/content. please tell me if my question is confusing.

i know there's a way using `order by desc id` or `date, limit 3` , but that comes in just one query, i was wondering if there's a way to just fetch the second to the latest and 3rd to the latest record. i know that the latest query can be written like `order by desc id` or `date, limit 1` , i just do not know how it is to query with the 2nd and 3rd to the latest record.

Comment: So my answer work or not for you ? What do you mean by another way ? What did you tried before you asked us here for help ? What are the errors you get ?

Comment: your answer will work if i'll fetch the latest 3 record. what i meant with another way is for ex with the latest record, the query will be something like `SELECT * FROM slider ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1`. but when i want to get the 2nd latest record, i no longer have an idea how to do it. i tried searching but all i get is how to fetch the latest 3 records all at once, which is not what i am trying to do. @androidnation

Comment: Try to fetch all rows in an array, and then get the 2nd last using its index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

```
-- latest
order by desc id/col_date desc limit 1

-- 2nd to latect
order by desc id/col_date desc limit 1,1

-- 3rd to latect
order by desc id/col_date desc limit 2,1
```

## Demo:

```
mysql> select * from (select 1 as a union select 2 union select 3) t;
+---+
| a |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
+---+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from (select 1 as a union select 2 union select 3) t order by a desc limit 1;
+---+
| a |
+---+
| 3 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from (select 1 as a union select 2 union select 3) t order by a desc limit 1,1;
+---+
| a |
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from (select 1 as a union select 2 union select 3) t order by a desc limit 2,1;
+---+
| a |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

## Reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these
>   exceptions:
>
> Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ?
>   placeholder markers.
>
> Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using
>   integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15

Comment: can u explain why 1,1 and 2,1? sorry, i just want to know why it is that way. :)

Comment: wow, you're a genius! thank you so much sir! it's much appreciated. and thank you also for the reference!